# Can testcases in .csv or excel format be imported in SOAP UI?

Tags: load-testing, web-service, soapui

I am using SOAP UI to test our RESTful search service. The search request is of the form :

```
 {               "className": "Pets",
                "searchType": "SearchResult",
                "query": "German shephard",
                "filterQuery": {"subClassName" = "Dogs"},
                "sortType": null,
                "startPageFrom": 0,
                "distance": 100.0,
                "latitude": 34.069784,
                "longitude": -118.34901,
                "pageSize": 20,
                "randomSeed": 0,
                "notBackfillable": false,
}
```

I want to test about 200 search terms (obtained from logs) along with multiple combinations of the other request parameters. The number of test cases can hence easily exceed thousand. Instead of creating each test  case in SOAP UI i would like to create an .csv or excel sheet to import these testcases in to SOAP UI (Which i can later run as load tests). Does anybody know of a way to do this? I have been through SOAP UI's documentation but haven't found anything useful. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option is only available in the PRO version of SOAP UI.  The license costs around 300 dollars a year.  You can have the data in an excel sheet and map the columns in the request; Loop it so that the test runs until all the rows in excel sheet are read and executed.  You can export the response to a CSV or excel sheet.

You might also find this useful: http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/functional-tests.html